# Postgres foreign data wrapper encoding issue

Tags: oracle, postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper, oracle-fdw

I'm trying to migrate Oracle data with '`we8mswin1252`' encoding to my [postgres](/questions/tagged/postgres) database which has '`UTF8`' encoding.

I'm using **foreign data wrapper**.

I'm getting

> `invalid byte sequence error`

What should i do?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation regarding [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such errors can be caused by two things:

- There may be zero bytes in your Oracle strings. That is allowed in Oracle (even though it is problematic), but forbidden in PostgreSQL.
- It is easy to get data corruption in Oracle, because it is pretty sloppy with encoding checks and allows you to insert arbitrary illegal byte sequences when client encoding and server encoding are the same.

There are two approaches to dealing with this problem:

- The correct way: fix the data on the Oracle side. `oracle_fdw` will support you by telling you which row in the result set caused the error.
- The sloppy way: use a PostgreSQL database with database encoding `sql_ascii`, which will allow you to store anything in a string (except zero bytes).

Comment: Laurenz, thanks for your reply, but can we create a database with sql_ascii encoding separately ? We have set it up in utf8 format. Also, we can't edit oracle data.

Comment: Sure: `CREATE DATABASE badchars ENCODING sql_ascii LC_COLLATE "C" LC_CTYPE "C" TEMPLATE template0;` Then you should set the `nls_lang` option on the foreign data wrapper to either use `WE8MSWIN1252` if you want the garbage data unchanged or `AS32UTF8` if you want them converted to UTF-8 as good as possible. Zero bytes will still be a problem.